# Area bounded by sine waves

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

The four curves are graphed
\begin{align*}
y&=\sin(x)\\
x&=\sin(y)\\
y&=\sin(x+\pi)+\pi\\
x&=\sin(y+\pi)+\pi
\end{align*}
These split the plane into many regions, but only one has a finite area. Compute this area.

I don't really know how to proceed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The area you need is 8 times the shaded area. Observe the equations carefully to see the symmetries. [image]

How to find it? Well you can see that (0,0) is where the curves meet.  And the right extreme of the interval is at $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$.  So the total area is $$8\int_0^{\pi/2}(x- \sin x) dx = 8\left( \frac{\pi^2}{8}-1\right)=\pi^2-8$$

Note: A zoom out to see that no other area is finite.[image]

Comment: How do you know the OP is asking that region ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Why the downvote?  What do you mean?  The question clearly says to find the *only* finite area that is bounded by the 4 curves.  If you plot them out by hand, it is easy to see that all other regions are infinite.  So what's the ambiguity?  Why would this not be the region?

Comment: Sorry, it's my bad.

Comment: (+1) and accepted because splitting the region into 8 equivalent regions simplifies calculations.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to solve this problem is to first draw a picture. Here's a photograph of the curves described in your problem:

[image]

The region bounding the finite area is a square who's sides are of length $\pi$. Calculating this area is simple. Now for the trickier bit: calculating the area beneath a sine wave. This can be solved by applying the methods of integration.

\begin{align*}
\int_0^\pi\sin(x)\,dx&=[-\cos(x)]_{0}^\pi\\
&=-\cos(\pi)+\cos(0)\\
&=2
\end{align*}

Since there are four of these sine waves, $A=\pi^2-4\int_0^\pi \sin(x)\,dx=\pi^2-8= 1.8696\ldots$

Comment: I like this way too! (+1)